# Is my application of a generator wrong here?

Tags: python, generator, python-3.6

I'm using the Facebook API and looking at the reactions for a post. FB limits responses to a max of 100 records but puts pagination to get the next lot etc.

My test case has well over 100 reactions (last count: 550) . What I want returned is a list of tuples where each tuple is a reaction to the post.

Here is what i have so far... the output list is over 100 less that expected-

```
import requests



def get_next_linksv3(page):
    while True:
    #try:
        r = requests.get(page)
        r_json = r.json()
        if 'paging' in r_json.keys() and 'next' in r_json['paging']:
            page = r_json['paging']['next']
            yield page
        else:
            return

def process_follow_on_reactions_link(next_link, list_reaction_tuples):
    nr = requests.get(next_link)
    r_json = nr.json()
    tmp_list = []
    if 'data' in r_json.keys():
        for nrecord in r_json['data']:
            reaction_id = nrecord['id']
            reaction_id_name = nrecord['name']
            reaction_type = nrecord['type']
            tmp_list.append((reaction_id,reaction_id_name,reaction_type))
    return tmp_list



def process_initial_reactions_link(link):
    list_reaction_tuples = []
    r = requests.get(link)
    r_json = r.json()
    if 'reactions' in r_json.keys():
        for record in r_json['reactions']['data']:
            reaction_id = record['id']
            reaction_id_name = record['name']
            reaction_type = record['type']
            list_reaction_tuples.append((reaction_id,reaction_id_name,reaction_type))
    if 'reactions' in r_json.keys() and 'paging' in r_json['reactions'] and 'next' in r_json['reactions']['paging']:
        next_link = r_json['reactions']['paging']['next']
        gen  = get_next_linksv3(next_link)
        while True:
            try:
                list_reaction_tuples = list_reaction_tuples + (process_follow_on_reactions_link(next(gen), list_reaction_tuples))
            except StopIteration:
                return list_reaction_tuples

    return list_reaction_tuples

tuple_list = process_initial_reactions_link(target_link)
```

Comment: where does it hang?

Comment: Please post the traceback.

Comment: I've edited the code so that it longer hangs but I'm now missing over 100 expected results.

Answer (score 0):

It may hang waiting for some data or spin in a loop. Most probably in the `while True` loop. When it gets an incorrect (or producing other output than desired) URL (the `if` condition is not satisfy), the generator constantly downloads the same page and never yields. You may want to introduce some `max_retries` variable instead of the `while True` loop.

Run the program under a debugger and pinpoint where it hangs. If it is impossible - use the simple print-debugging method. And show us the trace.

Comment: The OP can put an `r.raise_on_status()` line immedately after the page get to make this more obvious/easier